# add up value of 2 disabled inputs

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to add up the total of 2 disabled input boxes.. i keep getting a value of 0.. i think its because thats the value of when the page loads.. but im not sure.

my js:

```
$(document).on('change', '.var1', function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.var1').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(total)
});

$(document).on('change', '.var2', function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.var2').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum2').val(total)
});

$(document).ready(function(){
var a = +$('input[name=sum]').val();
var b = +$('input[name=sum2]').val();
var total = a+b;
$('#total').val(a+b);

});
```

html:

```
print "<select class=\"var1\" name=\"var1[$transnum]\">"; var1_list(); 
print "</select>\n";
print "<select class=\"var2\" name=\"var2[$transnum]\">"; var2_list(); 
print "</select>\n";

print "<input name=\"sum\" id=\"sum\" type=\"text\" size=\"4\"/ disabled>\n"; //add up 1
print "<input name=\"sum2\" id=\"sum2\" type=\"text\" size=\"4\"/ disabled>\n"; //add up 2
print "<input name=\"total\" id=\"total\" type=\"text\" size=\"4\"/ disabled>\n"; // add up total
```

Comment: Where is the code with class=var1 and var2?

Comment: Where is .var1 and .var2 in your html code?

Comment: i edited post... but that has nothing todo with what i want.. i just want to add up the values from the 2 sum disabled boxs

Comment: sum and sum2 add up the total from pulldown menu..that works fine.. i just want to add up the total from the 2 sum disabled boxs for #total

Comment: can you post the HTML as it appears on the page?

Comment: also... you only need one `$(document).ready(Function(){...});`  if you can update your question with the complete HTML i bet i can give you an answer in like 5 seconds.  oh, never mind, you are doing `$(document).on('change'..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did without knowing all the info.  http://jsfiddle.net/9neYY/

**edit** i had a typo in my first code and jsfiddle... i fixed it

```
// initialize things... 
update_sum();  
update_sum2(); 
update_total(); 

$(document).on('change', '.var1', function(){
    console.log('var 2 change'); 
    update_sum(); 
    update_total(); 
});

function update_sum(){ 
    var total = 0;
    $('.var1').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val(),10);
    });
    $('#sum').val(total);  
};

$(document).on('change', '.var2', function(){
    var total = 0;
    console.log('var 2 change'); 
    update_sum2(); 
    update_total(); 
});

function update_sum2(){ 
    var total = 0;
    $('.var2').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val(),10);
    });
    $('#sum2').val(total);  
};

function update_total(){
  var a = +$('input[name=sum]').val();
  var b = +$('input[name=sum2]').val();
  var total = a+b;
  $('#total').val(a+b); 
};
```

HTML I used:

```
<select class="var1" name="var1[]">
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=4>4</option>
    <option value=5>5</option>
</select>
<select class="var2" name="var2[]">
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=4>4</option>
    <option value=5>5</option>
</select><br/><br/>

Sum:<input name="sum" id="sum" type="text" size="4" disabled>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

Sum2: <input name="sum2" id="sum2" type="text" size="4" disabled>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

Total: <input name="total" id="total" type="text" size="4" disabled> <br/>
```

- I am not sure about your use of classes in the code...
- you need to include the base parameter in the [`parseInt`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function so that it is

  var value = $("#sum").val();
   var base = 10;
   var new_value = parseInt(value, base);

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on('change', '.var1', function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.var1').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(total)
    $('#total').val($('#sum').val()+$('#sum2').val());
});

$(document).on('change', '.var2', function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.var2').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum2').val(total)
    $('#total').val($('#sum').val()+$('#sum2').val());
});
```

The `#total` has be be calculated each time.

Answer (score 0):

beautifulcoder - thank you.. i used yours and edited it because it was giving me values 1+1=11..

this works:

```
$(document).on('change', '.var1', function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.var1').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(total)
    var a = +$('#sum').val();
    var b = +$('#sum2').val();
    $('#total').val(a+b);
});

$(document).on('change', '.var2', function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.var2').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum2').val(total)
    var a = +$('#sum').val();
    var b = +$('#sum2').val();
    $('#total').val(a+b);
});
```